# Share Facebook profile after Login - user_link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

We have a platform where users get logged in with Facebook. Now on customers demand, we want to provide a feature where we will request logged in users profile link at the time of login via user_link permission and user can share that link to anyone with just one tap. And on the other end, the other user who will receive this link will able to see (on facebook app or on Web) the sender's profile and if interested they can get connected.

But the issue is, I am not able to see user profile got as user_link. Its seems like I can only use this link if he or she is already my friend. If so then how can I implement this feature in my app? also if I am wrong at any point please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

> Its seems like I can only use this link if he or she is already my friend.

That’s exactly what the documentation says, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user:

> `link`: A link to the person's Timeline. The link will only resolve if the person clicking the link is logged into Facebook **and is a friend of the person whose profile is being viewed.**

-

> If so then how can I implement this feature in my app?

You can’t; Facebook has deliberately designed this feature with this restriction, to better protect people’s privacy.